# Do some running apps not show in Task Manager?

Tags: task-management

I was using the Navigator app and I was still hearing voice directions even though Task Manager showed no apps running. How can Task Manager show no apps and there could be an app still running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure which task manager you are using -- but some devices/Android versions distinguish running apps from services. On my Droid2 running Gingerbread, I find running apps at *Apps->Apps* in the "Running" Tab, while services show up at *Apps->Active Services*. Parts of Google Maps (which is the navigation app you probably refer to) are implemented as services, as e.g. the "location service" which keeps checking your GPS or Wifi based location in the background. I never used navigation itself, but I imagine this is handled similarly.

Comment: I am using the Task Manager which comes with the Galaxy Note

Comment: So the above should apply (I don't have a Galaxy Note to check, but I guess it is the stock TM there as well, not a 3rd party one). Did you check and find that second place for services, and does that answer your question?

Comment: I found the services area.